# Pandas - How to groupby and remove specifc rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF like this:

```
id     company     duration
0    Other Company    5
0    Other Company    19
0    X Company        7
1    Other Company    24
1    Other Company    6
1    X Company        12
2    X Company        9
3    Other Company    30
3    X Company        16
```

I need to group the DF by ID and Company and then sum the duration in each. In the end I need only the values with 'X Company'. This is what I did:

```
import pandas as pd
jobs = pd.read_csv("data/jobs.csv")
time_in_company = jobs.groupby(['id','company'])['duration'].agg(sum)
```

And got this:

```
id     company     duration
0    Other Company    24
0    X Company        7
1    Other Company    30
1    X Company        12
2    X Company        9
3    Other Company    30
3    X Company        16
```

Now I need remove all entrys from 'Other Company'. Already tried using  time_in_company.drop('Any Company') #Return KeyError 'Any Company'

Tried to .set_index('company'), in order to try something else, but it tells me 'Series' object has no attribute 'set_index'

Tried to use a .filter() in the groupby but I need the .agg(sum). (And it didn't work anyway..

Can someone shed some light in the issue for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: time_in_company [time_in_company ['company']!="Other Company"]

Comment: Got a pretty big traceback, but basically this: KeyError: 'company' **AND this:** TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: Your company variable has, in the background during the aggregation, been converted to a categorical variable and encoded, rather than remaining as a string, hence why the comparison to the string `"Other Company"` has failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
time_in_company= time_in_company.reset_index(level='company')
time_in_company [time_in_company ['company']!="Other Company"]
```

Comment: Didn't raise any error, but also didn't change anything in the df. I adjusted to time_in_company  = time_in_company [time_in_company ['company']!="Other Company"  - And it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First use [pd.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) to remove the 'X Company' rows, than [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) the remaining df like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


ids = [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,3,3]
company = ['Other Company','Other Company','X Company','Other Company','Other Company','X Company','X Company','Other Company','X Company']
duration = [5,19,7,24,6,12,9,30,16]

df = pd.DataFrame({'ids':ids,'company':company,'duration':duration})


df.query("company=='Other Company'").groupby(['ids','company'])['duration'].agg(sum)
```

You get:

```
ids  company      
0    Other Company    24
1    Other Company    30
3    Other Company    30
Name: duration, dtype: int64
```

**EDIT:** Additionally you can use a combination of [pd.where()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html), [dropna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)and [pd.pivot_table()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with:

```
df.where(df['company']=='Other Company').dropna().pivot_table(['duration'],index=['ids','company'],aggfunc='sum')
```

You get:

```
duration
ids company                
0.0 Other Company      24.0
1.0 Other Company      30.0
3.0 Other Company      30.0
```

Nonetheless, the firs one is faster:
2.03 ms ± 62.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
5.87 ms ± 23.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)